# Put a value in a read-only textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, textbox

I have a form with many textboxes. I would like to disable the operation of user interaction with 2 or more textboxes but i would like to assign some text to it. I cannot figure it out a way to do it ...

I have the following code:

```
 If tablead.Rows(0)(4) = True Then
        TextBox2.Text = "0"
        TextBox2.ReadOnly = True
        TextBox2.Text = "0"
 End If
```

When i run it the textbox goes "read-only" but the value 0 is not shown. Why ?

Comment: Does this fire at all?  Put a stop on the first "TextBox2.Text = 0" and see if it does.

Comment: Where do you have this code? Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly.aspx ?

Comment: Do you have Option Strict On?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it somewhat right, however you need to provide more code.

The

```
If tablead.Rows(0)(4) = True then
   TextBox2.Text = "0"
   TextBox2.ReadOnly = True
End If
```

is sufficent to achieve what you're aiming for, but for some reason it never fires the event that
you've put this code in. Do have a look and see if there's something else happening that makes it jump this code.